# how to fail an airflow task based on response to command prompt

Tags: sql-server, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have this task in airflow:

```
def bcp_in(set):
    files = []
    for file in glob.glob(Variable.get("temp_directory") + "offrs/{}*.txt".format(set)):
        files.append(file)
    print("LOCAL FILES {}".format(files))
    for file in files:
        print('Importing File {}'.format(file))
        cmd = '/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp buyerhero_staging.dbo.FILETYPE IN "{file}" -F2  -<<HOST>> -<<PASSWORD>> -S<<SERVER>> -t"|" -c'.format(table=set, file=file)
        print(os.popen(cmd).read())


BCP_Import_FILETYPE_Files = PythonOperator(
    task_id='BCP_Import_Files_to_DB3_Staging',
    python_callable=bcp_in,
    op_kwargs={'set': 'FILETYPE'},
    dag=dag
)
```

if everything works, is ok.
However, I need to fail the task if BCP fails.  for example:

```
[2020-01-23 02:45:08,786] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - Importing File /home/airflow/airflow/staging/FILETYPE_000000000000.csv
[2020-01-23 02:45:09,505] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - 
Starting copy...
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification

BCP copy in failed
[2020-01-23 02:45:09,505] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO -
```

This BCP failed, but the task is still showing green.  I wouldn't have known to troubleshoot if I wasn't looking in the log.

How do I report task failure in this circumstance.
Or, if better....does anyone have a better operator for feeding CSV/TXT files into MSSQL?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `subprocess.check_ouput` to run your command, example:

```py
import subprocess

def bcp_in(set):
    files = []
    for file in glob.glob(Variable.get("temp_directory") + "offrs/{}*.txt".format(set)):
        files.append(file)
    print("LOCAL FILES {}".format(files))
    for file in files:
        print('Importing File {}'.format(file))
        cmd = '/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp buyerhero_staging.dbo.FILETYPE IN "{file}" -F2  -<<HOST>> -<<PASSWORD>> -S<<SERVER>> -t"|" -c'.format(table=set, file=file)
        subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```

Details: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

> If the return code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError. The CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode attribute and any output in the output attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [-e](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#e) bcp option to write any errors to a file, and then use the contents of the file to decide on the task success.